# Radeon HD5670 hangs after login

Tags: 12.04, ati, radeon

Thanks in advance for your advices.

I installed, Ubuntu 12.04 today, on my PC with a Radeon hd5670 graphics card. The first error I encountered, (just like the first time Unity came out - after witch I waited to try Ubuntu again until now) is, that it hanged after login at the desktop wallpaper, with only the mouse cursor. Well actually the first problem was with the live CD, but I managed to install it, using the install now, not the try now. Live CD has the same problem, as after install. 
So, after installing and getting the error, I searched of course before asking this:) 
I found this: [Ubuntu hangs at purple screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/120096/ubuntu-hangs-at-purple-screen)

The accepted answer there helped me to get to this. (note, that the below picture is a screen taken from a working desktop, and then erased the parts that don't show on mine.)

[image]

Note that there is nothing at the top except the brown bar. No shutdown button, no nothing. The system hangs, I can't click on anything, I can only wiggle around with my mouse XD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I continued my research.

For testing purposes I've installed gnome3 from the console. After that I've noticed a mistake I've made. I've forgotten to test the Ubuntu 2D desktop enviroment.

So I did it quick, and Ubuntu 2D works perfect. Then I've tried gnome. Gnome3 and Gnome classic do the same thing as the Unity desktop. Namely freeze. So I've tried Gnome classis(no effects) and of course, that works.

So conclusion: 
Unity/Gnome/Gnome Classic - produce the same problem
Unity 2D/Gnome Classic (no effects) - work flawless

Then I've decided to reinstall my ati drivers using: [What is the correct way to install proprietary ATI Catalyst Video Drivers (fglrx) directly from AMD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-ati-catalyst-video-drivers)
The outcome remained the same.

Of course I've confirmed if the drivers were working using: "fglrxinfo"
And they are working.
Then I've decided to try out some games. And the outcome: the games work 100% no problem.

At this point I'm done with trying, and accepted the fact, that this is the best thing I can get, at this point in time.

Final thoughts.

The first time Unity came out, the problem stuck at the drivers. No games would work, all would freeze. Only Gnome classic (no effects) worked at that time. I'm happy to see, that this is some form of improvemen. Because altough I can't use the defauld desktop, I can use Ubuntu the way I want, well at least to this point in time. Video card demanding thigs seem to work correctly, desktop is usable. The problem I have is, that in this state Ubuntu isn't as user friendly as it wants to be. You can't give somebody an Install disk and rest easy, because you know, that there will be something wrong. In my opinion, Ubuntu takes steps forward, but unfortunately it also takes steps backward. Well the final test will of course be, steam and Left 4 Dead 2, if it really comes out.

Thank you for your time.