# Gigabyte - AMD radeon R7 250 issues

Tags: 12.04, fglrx

I used ubuntu 12.04LTS. My Desktop can't start up after I installed the FGLRX from Additional Drivers in the System Setting menu. It stop at start-up purple screen. How can I fix this error?

Comment: Do you get a black screen?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to open any of the default Ubuntu text terminals by pressing:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>FX</kbd>

where X in function key <kbd>FX</kbd> can be any number on your keyboard (for example, <kbd>F4</kbd> or <kbd>F5</kbd>)

Have in mind, that function key <kbd>F7</kbd> is reserved for the graphical terminal (where your FGLRX driver has crashed), thus you should use a different terminal.

Basically what you want is reconfigure xorg.conf (Xorg display server configuration file). You can do this by simply typing:

```
sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

After removing/reconfiguring the xorg.conf file, start the Xorg server with this command:

```
sudo startx
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply but I don't get a black screen. Nothing happen when I press Ctrl+Alt+FX (I tried X from 0 to 9).

Comment: Uhm, you then might try going into recovery mode, try this answer:
http://askubuntu.com/a/120168/16981